# SerialPort.Datarecieved problems

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the SerialPort.DataReceived Event. Let me explain my problem.
I have 1 form lets call this mainform.cs and i have a class pumpfuntions.cs, in pumpfunctions.cs i make my serialport and make the function that i need with the serialport.

What i want is that my received data goes into an textbox. But the problem is that my Datareceived class is in my pumpfunctions.cs.

How can i solve this.

**Code Pumpfunctions.cs:**

```
Class PumpFunctions
    {

        private SerialPort _comport = new SerialPort();
        public string RxString;

        public void SerialPortDataReceived()
        {
            if (_comport.DataReceived != false)
            {
                string ReadData = _comport.ReadExisting();


                RxString = ReadData;
            }
        }

        public void OpenSerialPort()
        {
            _comport.PortName = "COM6";
            _comport.BaudRate = 9600;
            _comport.Open();

        }

        public void CloseSerialPort()
        {
            _comport.Close();

        }
}
```

**Code Mainform.cs**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private PumpFunctions _pump = new PumpFunctions();
        private String rxString;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _pump.OpenSerialPort();

        }

private void SerialPortDataReceived()
        {
            string rxString = _pump.RxString;
            //this.Invoke(new EventHandler(_commandTextbox_TextChanged));

        }

        private void _commandTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (rxString)
            {
                case "\r\n:": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Stopped\r\n"); break;
                case "\r\n>": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Running forward\r\n"); break;
                case "\r\n<": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Running reverse\r\n"); break;
                case "\r\n*": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Stalled\r\n"); break;
                case "\r\n*|": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Infuse limit switch activated\r\n"); break;
                case "\r\n*W": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Withdraw limit switch activated\r\n"); break;
                case "\r\n*D": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Disable by emergency stop\r\n"); break;
                case "\r\n*T": _commandTextbox.AppendText("Status: Target volume reached\r\n"); break;
                default: _commandTextbox.AppendText(rxString); break;
            }
        }




    }
```

Can someone explain to me what to problem is.

Also this is the error im getting

Error   1

```
The event 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.DataReceived' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataReceived is an **event** exposed by SerialPort class.
You register this event with delegate when you want to receive the data from the port.

You **cant** check if the event is true/false. you can check if there are subscribers on it.
read about the class here [SerialPort MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)

Example for program that creates Serialport and register the event:

```
class Program
{
    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM6", 1200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        serialPort.Open();
        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    static void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var length = serialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, length);

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            if (buffer.Length >= 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ok with = > " + buffer.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so how do i do it then?

Comment: if i would use your code does it has to be in mainform.cs or in pumpfunctions.cs?

Comment: In OpenSerialPort you need to register the event with your delegate (function), and remove the if (_comport.DataReceived != false) from within the function

Comment: You need to register the event with your _comport.DataReceived +=SerialPortDataReceived(), BUT - your function signature is not right, it should be like mine: **serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)** with parameters

Comment: N.P just had to work with that class yesterday, feel free to ask more :)